# Laravel Blade - loop for

Tags: laravel, loops, for-loop, laravel-blade

How can i do it:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++)
   @if ($categorie->t$i != null)
       {{$categorie->t$i}}
   @endif                                            
@endfor
```

categorie->t$i = categorie->t1 , t2, t3 ... t10.

Thanks !

Comment: if `$categorie->t` is an array then do this `$category->t[$i]`

Comment: Nop, i have already tried this. t is not a array. I've a table categorie, with t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 for title. 10 title different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the item t$i by concatinating the string 't' with the value of $i, and afterwards accessing this.

First:

```
$item_name = 't' . $i;
```

Then:

```
$category->$item_name
```

This should do the trick.